# CSS border animation not working on object

Tags: css

On a website, I was creating an object that that had a border animation on it. I had searched this question a lot of times on Stack Overflow and google, but no solution worked. My animation animated the border:

```
.object-color {
    -webkit-animation: color 1.5s linear infinite alternate both;
         animation: color 1.5s linear infinite alternate both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color{
  14.3% {
    color: red;
    background-color: #e0ffff !important;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    border: 1px solid green !important;
  }
  28.6% {
    color: green;
    background-color: #e0ffff !important;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    border: 1px solid red !important;
  }
  100% {
    color: green;
    background-color: #e0ffff !important;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    border: 1px solid red !important;
  }
}
```

However, when it was applied, the border didn't animate and had no color. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well (to confirm your selector targets)? It's almost impossible to answer this question without it. It would help if you could update your question to list all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your use of `!important` inside of keyframes. Simply removing the `!important` declarations will cause your animation to work:

```css
.object-color {
  -webkit-animation: color 1.5s linear infinite alternate both;
  animation: color 1.5s linear infinite alternate both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color {
  14.3% {
    color: red;
    background-color: #e0ffff;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
  28.6% {
    color: green;
    background-color: #e0ffff;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  100% {
    color: green;
    background-color: #e0ffff;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="object-color">Hi</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Err...I was more of the border color not working, sorry. I did what you suggested, and the border is still not changing color. Hope I don't sound too pushy. (By the way, I'm styling a reddit css stylesheet for the flairs, so I'm not sure how to post the output).

Comment: No problem; you're certainly not being pushy at all! Though the border colour is indeed changing in my above snippet. If the border colour is not changing for you, it's possible there's another selector targeting that element with a higher level of [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). Try increasing your level of specificity on the **selector itself**, without resorting to `!important` declarations.